# Tkinter scrollbar isn't working after adding to Toplevel() window

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got a scrollbar inside my tkinter interface. It used to work no problem when it was inside of the main tkinter window. I've recently made some changes and placed the scrollable frame inside of a Toplevel() pop-up window. I've adjusted all of the related attributes so that the Toplevel() window is the new master, this is (self.pop_up), but I can no longer move the scrollbar?

Here's the code relevant to the scrollbar:

```
# create a container canvas then place a scrollbar and frame on top
container = ttk.Frame(self.pop_up)
canvas = tk.Canvas(master=container, height=self.pop_up_height, width=self.pop_up_width)
scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas, height=self.pop_up_height, width=self.pop_up_width)

# bind the scroll function
scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

# define the window position
canvas.create_window((10, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="n")

# link the canvas to the scrollbar
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
```

Here's what the pop-up looks like:
[image]

And here's the full class which will create the window (the relevant code is in the generate_labels method:

```
class UnicodeWindow:
    """ class for creating the unicode pop-up window """

    def __init__(self):
        # create the pop-up
        self.pop_up = tk.Toplevel()
        self.pop_up.wm_title('')

        # define the pop up dimensions
        self.pop_up_width = g.screen_width // 3
        self.pop_up_height = g.screen_height // 2

        # create the pop-up font
        self.window_font = font.Font(size=26, family='Courier New')

        # resize the window and make it central
        self.pop_up.geometry(
            f"{self.pop_up_width}x{self.pop_up_height}+{g.screen_width // 3}+{g.screen_height // 4}")

        # add the select block message
        self.message = tk.Label(self.pop_up, text='\n\nSelect a Block\n', font=self.window_font)
        self.message.pack()

        # add the block buttons
        self.basic_latin_button = tk.Button(self.pop_up, text='Basic Latin', command=self.basic_latin, font=self.window_font,
                                            width=20, pady=10)
        self.basic_latin_button.pack()

        self.l_supplement_button = tk.Button(self.pop_up, text='Latin Supplement', command=self.l_supplement, font=self.window_font,
                                             width=20, pady=10)
        self.l_supplement_button.pack()

        self.latin_a_button = tk.Button(self.pop_up, text='Latin Extended-A', command=self.latin_a, font=self.window_font,
                                        width=20, pady=10)
        self.latin_a_button.pack()

        self.latin_b_button = tk.Button(self.pop_up, text='Latin Extended-B', command=self.latin_b, font=self.window_font,
                                        width=20, pady=10)
        self.latin_b_button.pack()

        self.exit_button = tk.Button(self.pop_up, text='Return', command=self.exit, font=self.window_font, width=20,
                                     pady=10)
        self.exit_button.pack()

        # load the unicode dataframe
        self.df = pd.read_csv('../unicode/unicode_db.csv')

    def basic_latin(self):
        self.block = 'Basic Latin'
        self.generate_labels()

    def l_supplement(self):
        self.block = 'Latin-1 Supplement'
        self.generate_labels()

    def latin_a(self):
        self.block = 'Latin Extended-A'
        self.generate_labels()

    def latin_b(self):
        self.block = 'Latin Extended-B'
        self.generate_labels()

    def generate_labels(self):
        """ function for displaying the unicode based on what block has been selected """
        # destroy the original pop-up
        self.pop_up.destroy()

        # change the window geometry
        self.pop_up_width = g.screen_width // 2

        # create new pop-up
        self.pop_up = tk.Toplevel()
        self.pop_up.wm_title('')

        # create the symbol font
        symbol_font = font.Font(size=34, family='Courier New')
        unicode_font = font.Font(size=10, family='Courier New')

        # define the offset distance between symbols and their unicode
        offset = 1.7

        # resize the window and make it central
        self.pop_up.geometry(
            f"{self.pop_up_width}x{self.pop_up_height}+{g.screen_width // 4}+{g.screen_height // 4}")

        # create a container canvas then place a scrollbar and frame on top
        container = ttk.Frame(self.pop_up)
        canvas = tk.Canvas(master=container, height=self.pop_up_height, width=self.pop_up_width)
        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
        scrollable_frame = ttk.Frame(canvas, height=self.pop_up_height, width=self.pop_up_width)

        # bind the scroll function
        scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")))

        # define the window position
        canvas.create_window((10, 0), window=scrollable_frame, anchor="n")

        # link the canvas to the scrollbar
        canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        # get sub dataframe of relevant unicode
        sub_df = self.df[self.df.block == self.block]

        # iterate through unicode 8 at a time, creating the labels
        count = 0
        while len(sub_df) > 0:
            if len(sub_df) >= 8:
                next_uni = sub_df[:8]
            else:
                next_uni = sub_df

            for index, row in next_uni.iterrows():
                unicode = row['unicode']
                symbol = chr(int(unicode, 16))
                symbol_label = ttk.Label(master=scrollable_frame, text=symbol, font=symbol_font)
                symbol_label.place(x=((index % 8 + 1) * (self.pop_up_width / 10)),
                                   y=(count + 1) * (self.pop_up_height // 8))
                unicode_label = ttk.Label(master=scrollable_frame, text=unicode, font=unicode_font)
                unicode_label.place(x=((index % 8 + 1) * (self.pop_up_width / 10)),
                                    y=(count + offset) * (self.pop_up_height // 8))

            if len(sub_df) < 8:
                break

            # drop rows already visited
            sub_df = sub_df[8:]

            count += 1

        canvas.pack()
        container.pack()
        scrollbar.place(x=self.pop_up_width*0.98, y=10)
        #scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")

        # add the return button
        rturn_button = tk.Button(self.pop_up, command=self.rturn, text='Return', width=20, font=self.window_font, pady=10)
        rturn_button.place(x=self.pop_up_width/2, y=self.pop_up_height*0.85)
        rturn_button.update()
        rturn_width = rturn_button.winfo_width()
        rturn_button.place(x=(self.pop_up_width/2 - rturn_width/2) , y=self.pop_up_height * 0.85)

    def exit(self):
        """ function for exiting the pop-up window """
        self.pop_up.destroy()

    def rturn(self):
        """ function for returning to the parent unicode menu """
        self.pop_up.destroy()
        self.__init__()
```

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve].

Comment: better create minimal working code which we could simply copy and run to see problem and test ideas for solution.

Comment: Yeah usually I would, it's a lot of code so I wasn't sure If I should include everything in this case. I've now updated the question to include everything

Comment: There's also still a lot of editing to be done in terms of separating code out into different methods and adding docstrings - I've been overhauling the entire application so at the moment I'm just focussing on getting everything working properly

Comment: the point of [mre] sometimes is that you create new code that specifically reproduces the problem and keeps it very compact, you have to remove all the code that doesn't reproduce the problem, this may also help you solve the problem yourself since you will see which line of code is causing the issue

Comment: You have used `.place()` on those labels, so they won't affect the size of `scrollable_frame`.  Therefore, the `scrollregion` will not be updated and the scrollbar will not work as you expect.  Use `.grid()` on those labels instead.

Comment: @acw1668 I had no idea that's what was causing the problem, I originally used grid to position the labels in the old setup, but since the overhaul I've tried to avoid using grid completely. I just assumed the issue had something to do with changing my Toplevel() window to the new master, so I was looking in the wrong place completely haha. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Matiiss Yeah I guess I never considered that I could've stripped the code down a lot just to create a sample of the problem, which may have helped me spot the issue myself. It turns out that the problem wasn't in the original code sample that I posted, so a full example of the code was definitely needed. I'll know for next time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that this error occurs as a result of using `place()` to position my labels within `scrollable_frame`. As a result of this, `scrollregion` wasn't updating, which meant that there wasn't anywhere for the scrollbar to take me. The fix was to use `grid()` to position the `scrollable_frame` labels instead:

```
i = 0
for index, row in next_uni.iterrows():
    unicode = row['unicode']
    symbol = chr(int(unicode, 16))

    symbol_label = ttk.Label(master=scrollable_frame, text=symbol, font=symbol_font)

    unicode_label = ttk.Label(master=scrollable_frame, text=unicode, font=unicode_font)
               
    symbol_label.grid(row=(2 * count), column=i, ipadx=self.pop_up_width//20)
    unicode_label.grid(row=(2 * count + 1), column=i, ipadx=self.pop_up_width//20)

    i += 1
```

Comment: Big thanks to @acw1668, who spotted the issue and pointed me in the right direction!

Comment: If you're able to use computed locations, there's no need to use grid or an inner frame. That's adding more complexity than is necessary. You can simply create the labels directly on the canvas with `create_text`.